# Integration by parts, the Möbius function and the Apéry's contant

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, mobius-function

I believe that **by integration by parts** for $\int_0^1u\cdot dv$, see the dot here to define the formula (after we sum for a sufficently large integer)
$$\sum_{k=3}^\infty\int_0^1\frac{d}{dx}x^{\mu(k)}\cdot\frac{x^{k-1}}{k^2}dx=\frac{1}{\zeta(3)}-(1-\frac{1}{2^3})-2\sum_{\substack{k\geq 3},\mu(k)=-1}\frac{1}{k^3(k-2)},$$
where $\mu(k)$ is the **Möbius function**.

And in the other hand with a new integration by parts defined as  $\int_0^1u\cdot dv$, see the dot here to define the formula
$$\sum_{k=3}^\infty\int_0^1\frac{x^{k-1}}{k^2}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}x^{\mu(k)}dx=
(\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1-\frac{1}{4})-\sum_{\substack{k\geq 3},\mu(k)=0}\frac{1}{k^2}$$

$$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad-\sum_{\substack{k\geq 3},\mu(k)=1}\frac{k+1}{k^3}-\sum_{\substack{k\geq 3},\mu(k)=-1}\frac{k-1}{k^2(k-2)}.$$
Then notice that if there are no mistakes it is possible to get $\frac{1}{\zeta(3)}$ as function of $\sum_{\substack{k\geq 3},\mu(k)=0}\frac{1}{k^2}$, since the term $$-\left(\sum_{\substack{k\geq 3},\mu(k)=1}\frac{k+1}{k^3}-\sum_{\substack{k\geq 3},\mu(k)=-1}\frac{k+1}{k^3}\right)=$$
is equals to $$-\left(\frac{1}{\zeta(2)}-(1-\frac{1}{2^2})+\frac{1}{\zeta(3)}-(1-\frac{1}{2^3})\right).$$

> **Question.** Please can you find where was the first of my mistakes? I say this because the computations were tedious. If it is possible/feasible, **can you obtain an identity with mathematical meaning or the final identity that I've presumed** (I say if you can get a simple identity involving the $\frac{1}{\zeta(3)}$ from this approach)? **Thanks in advance.**

I've tried different integrands in integrals as $$\int_0^1\frac{d}{dx}x^{\mu(k)}\cdot d\left(\frac{x^{k-1}}{k^2}\right),$$
defined also for $k$ sufficiently large (or leaving easy calculations for the corresponding tail), say us $k\geq 4$.

Comment: **Lemma.** One has that  for each $k\geq 1$

i) $\Big(\frac{d}{dx}x^{\mu(k)}\Big|_{x=1}=\mu(k)$,

ii) $ \frac{d}{dx}x^{\mu(k)} =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $\mu(k)=0$} \\
1, & \text{if $\mu(k)=1$}\\
-1/x^{2}, & \text{if $\mu(k)=-1$}
\end{cases},$ and 

iii) $ \frac{d}{dx} \left(  \frac{d}{dx}x^{\mu(k)} \right) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $\mu(k)=0$} \\
0, & \text{if $\mu(k)=1$}\\
2/x^3, & \text{if $\mu(k)=-1$}
\end{cases}.$

Comment: I noticed that you ask a lot of questions about Apéry's constant. If you don't mind me asking, is your goal to find the exact sum ("closed form") of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^3}$? I ask because that is one of my major goals in mathematics.

Comment: I do not care to answer it, my situation in my real life is not the best , and only with very motivating problems can encourage to me to study more  mathematics. The best answer should be what I follow the advice of one of the users here, when they said to me *to take a book*, for example of complex analysis *and read it*. I lose a lot of the time, and additionaly  if in next years I have a collection of failed attempts, and little knowledge in mathematics, perhaps I have not made ​​the best decisions to improve and move forward. Thanks @zerosofthezeta